# NODEJS - calling one endpoint from another falls into CATCH even tho it successfully finishes

Tags: node.js

I have these two endpoints  (it's simplified but the idea/problem remains the same) ...

**/api/v1/update**

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {

  Data.update({salary: 1})
  .then(data => {
    console.log("All good")
    return res.status(200).send({message: "OK"})
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Oh Crap!")
    return res.status(400).send(error)
  })

}
```

and

***/api/v1/process*** in which I call the first one as part of the processing

```
exports.process = (req, res) => {

  axios.get('http://localhost:8008/api/v1/update')
  .then(data => {
    console.log("You got it")
    return res.status(200).send(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Not working!")
    return res.status(400).send(error)
  })

}
```

This is what I getting in the console:

```
$>: nodemon server.js
Server running on port 8008
All good
Not working!
```

How come the axios call is successfully (the "update" endpoint) finished but it falls into CATCH instead of THEN ?

What am I missing?

EDIT:

ok I figured it out..the error was in the `return res.status(200).send(data)` of /api/v1/process ...

Error: Converting circular structure to JSON

So what I did was I extracted the values (response of the first endpoint -> update) and send it afterwards :) it's working great now ... silly mistake

*facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error was in the return res.status(200).send(data) of /api/v1/process ...

Error: Converting circular structure to JSON

So what I did was I extracted the values (response of the first endpoint -> update) and send it afterwards :) it's working great now ... silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that the controller return undefined, only after executing then it tries to return and execute the `res.send`.
For this kinda problems i use `async/await` to simplify async calls

```js
exports.update = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Data.update({salary: 1});
    res.status(200).send({message: "OK"});

  } catch(error) {
    console.log("Oh Crap!")
    res.status(400).send(error)
  }
}
```

Also check the error details in axios:

```js
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Not working!", error);
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  })
```

Comment: ok that's a nice idea.. didn't think about async :) lemme try that ...

Comment: ok got it... it wasn't the async... but I pulled out the error and it said `Converting circular structure to JSON` .. see more details in the original post (edited).. anyway thx for the suggestions

Comment: Thanks, I will delete my answer so